# In java, is it possible to convert a decimal value from 0 to 15 inclusive to a hexadecimal character using the char function?

Tags: java, char, ascii

For example, I want to convert 11 to B by casting char. In another exercise I was able to do (char)(69) to get E, I need to do something similar. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible...

Comment: but how do i do it?

Comment: I tried using (char)(11) but it didnt work.

Comment: If `char(69)` gives you an E, why would you think `char(11)` would give you a B?

Comment: wait oops that was dumb... how do you do it?

Comment: Why not use [toHexString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int))?...

Comment: hi! i have to do the char casting for an assignment.

Comment: In that case, figure out how to convert 10 to 65, 11, to 66, 12 to 67, etc.  Hint: Add a Number...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using (char)(11) but it didnt work

This is a little bit naïve approach, please have a look at the [character table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

> want to convert 11 to B by casting char

Nope, this is not the way. Characters in theory could have any value from the range, but in Java the char is intended for printable characters

Representing numbers in different formats is called *encoding*.

You can do it yourself, see https://www.baeldung.com/java-byte-arrays-hex-strings

```
 char[] hexDigits = new char[2];
 hexDigits[0] = Character.forDigit((num >> 4) & 0xF, 16);
 hexDigits[1] = Character.forDigit((num & 0xF), 16);
```

or you can use an out-of-box [encoder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html).

there are some [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)) for basic conversion, as in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Java has some methods within the `Integer` class such as:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(int i);
Integer.toOctalString(int i);
Integer.toHexString(int i);
```

The third on converts an integer to hexadecimal representation. If your number is in the variable `num` then you can convert it in hexadecimal like so:

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(num);
```

This will turn the number from decimal to hexadecimal.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 10;
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(num);
        System.out.println(hex);
    }
}
```

This will give the following output:

```
a
```

If you want the letters to be capital, add `hex = hex.toUpperCase();` after 
`String hex = Integer.toHexString(num);`. The `toUpperCase()` method turns all lowercase letters in a String to uppercase without changing any of the other characters.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 10;
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(num);
        hex = hex.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(hex);
    }
}
```

Now this code will give:

```
A
```